# "Exception: Bad request:" occured when running custom formula to retrieve URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can't seem to get custom formula #2 "FindHandleName()" (that retrieves the handle name from the URL that's retrieved by custom formula #1 "getRedirect()") to populate as per normal. Might be an issue with the URL that's input in column B(?).

Sample sheet to test - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SC_ZMhbB7ekCsgaQlgyOZwxupyjDGIdoShqMWwSdKLs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification for `getRedirect(url)`:

```
function getRedirect(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false});
  var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location'];
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  Logger.log(responseCode);
  var nextURL = UrlFetchApp.fetch(redirectUrl, {'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false}).getAllHeaders()['Location'];
  Logger.log(nextURL);

  return nextURL;
}
```

on `FindHandleName()`:

from `sheet.getRange(2+index,5).setValue(result[3]);` to the following.

```
sheet.getRange(2+index,5).setValue(result[1]);
```

Output:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Added try-catch as suggested to handle 404 errors.

```
function getRedirect(url) {
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false});
  var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location'];
  Logger.log(redirectUrl)
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  Logger.log(responseCode);
  try{
     var nextURL = UrlFetchApp.fetch(redirectUrl, {'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false}).getAllHeaders()     ['Location'];
     Logger.log(nextURL);
  }
  catch(err){
     Logger.log(err);
     nextURL = '/VIDEO DELETED';
  }finally{
     return nextURL;
  }
}
```

NOTES:

Results sometimes returns a `null` or `undefined` this may be due to the second redirect returning a null response due to multiple calls.

Comment: Would you mind sending over the sheet you're using? I can't seem to replicate the result in your snippet.

Comment: oh wait, my bad. I did a few changes as well on `FindHandleName()`. I'll edit the answer above

Comment: Thanks, @Diego Sanchez! It's working great now!

Comment: If you were to do this whole process, how would you make this better? Am open to reoptimizing this whole process.

Comment: What you currently have right now is already good, what you just need to continue is to find a way to skip the URLs that return a responseCode 404 and that should seemlessly populate all the publicly available data you are gathering

Comment: Any suggestion on that? Can't quite figure out how to go about it for the life of me.

Comment: Implemented a simple try-catch..finally as posted above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247356/discussion-between-qazamy-and-diego-sanchez).